# OpenAM Web Policy Agent not redirecting user with expired session to authenticate, but 403 page instead

Tags: single-sign-on, openam

I'm using OpenAM 13 and Web Policy Agent 4.0 for apache.

It seems that Web Policy Agent could not recognize an **iPlanetDirectoryPro** cookie, which is a token set by OpenAM after authentication, is expired or is actually an invalid one.

Looks like Web Policy Agent would take the token and confirm it with OpenAM, then be told the validation failed, like these lines of log below, and give the user a 403 forbidden page.

```
2017-01-24 11:29:55.475 +0800 WARNING [0x7f180e887700:17669] am_get_session_policy_cache_entry(): failed to locate data for a key (AQIC5wM2LY4SfcxFG6Bl98dRT7AluZ7682rulJGU8-CCSN4.*AAJTSQACMDEAAlNLABQtMTQ2NTcwMTgyOTEwMjQ5MTg4OQACUzEAAA..*)
2017-01-24 11:29:55.484 +0800 WARNING [0x7f180e887700:17669] validate_policy(): retry 0 (remote session/policy call failure: error)
2017-01-24 11:29:57.490 +0800 WARNING [0x7f180e887700:17669] validate_policy(): retry 1 (remote session/policy call failure: error)
2017-01-24 11:29:59.497 +0800 WARNING [0x7f180e887700:17669] validate_policy(): retry 2 (remote session/policy call failure: error)
2017-01-24 11:30:01.504 +0800 WARNING [0x7f180e887700:17669] validate_policy(): retry 3 (remote session/policy call failure: error)
2017-01-24 11:30:03.504 +0800 ERROR [0x7f180e887700:17669] validate_policy(): remote session/policy call to validate 'http://agent.job.com.tw:80/notification/push' failed (max 3 retries exhausted)
```

The expected behavior under that situation is redirect the user to auth, I think so, if the user is valid and has no permission to access that page, agent would be instructed to block the user out of it, like this one below.

```
2017-01-24 11:43:59.009 +0800 WARNING [0x7f17f9ff3700:17669] am_get_session_policy_cache_entry(): failed to locate data for a key (AQIC5wM2LY4Sfcz6gBnS77c_KhZogqv6gYGQdjU1WpRaQxE.*AAJTSQACMDEAAlNLABMzMTYxMjIwNDAzNjc4NDA4MDQxAAJTMQAA*)
2017-01-24 11:43:59.050 +0800 WARNING [0x7f17f9ff3700:17669] validate_policy(): decision: deny, reason: no action decisions found
2017-01-24 11:43:59.213 +0800 WARNING [0x7f180d000700:17669] validate_policy(): validate policy did not find a match for 'http://agent.job.com.tw:80/favicon.ico' in the cached entries, retrying with the new request to the policy service
2017-01-24 11:43:59.227 +0800 WARNING [0x7f180d000700:17669] validate_policy(): decision: deny, reason: no action decisions found
```

However, if I navigate to the OpenAM server page by myself, regardless before or after accessing the resource page and get a 403 page back, OpenAM would ask me to auth! On other words, to login, and the **iPlanetDirectoryPro** cookie disappeared, I guess it was cleared by OpenAM, so this means that OpenAM is able to distinguish an expired session, or at least, it knows how to take care of an **iPlanetDirectoryPro** cookie which is no longer effective.

If I choose not to login immediately, and head back to the resource page, it starts to redirect to OpenAM for authentication which is good. When getting 403 page, remove the **iPlanetDirectoryPro** cookie manually will do the same trick.

Well this is really annoying, and could be critical for general users, they won't be aware to do those workaround mentioned above.

I wish there's somebody kind could help me with this problem, many thanks.

Comment: In general this works, so there seems to be specific issue with your deployment. In Agent 4 the caching of SSOToken changed. It's now cached as long as the 'maxCachingTime' is configured on the OpenAM server side. When the SSO Session times out and Agent is configured for notification mode OpenAM also sends out a notification  to Agent to clean the cache.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I had this issue on my test environment also, a Ubuntu VM which only configured by following the steps in the [Getting Started With OpenAM](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13/getting-started) and [OpenAM Web Policy Agent Release Notes](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam-web-policy-agents/4/web-release-notes). The maxCachingTime option you mentioned is 3 mins by default, I tried to change it to 0 but the issue still remain. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are running into this bug: [AMAGENTS-279](https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/AMAGENTS-279)

Comment: [AMAGENTS-279](https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/AMAGENTS-279) looks pretty much the same to the issue I'm having here.  But I also found that if my browser restore the last opened tabs at start, and I didn't close the 403 tab before quit, it still get 403 after start. I had read the release note and found there was an issue [OPENAM-8088](https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-8088) looks similar to which I had encountered, and was fixed in Agents 4.0.1 only for subscriber. And I'm not pretty sure the problem I'm facing is exact that one, cause the term used there is session.

Comment: But if I do close the 403 page, and restart my browser, open a new tab and access to the page, will redirect me to auth which is what I wanted. It seems that what I could do is wait till the issue fixed, and avoid to use a browser to access the protected resource which will keep working longer than the max session time or the max session idle time before the fix arrive. Thanks you for the issue information.